# 90% Confidence Interval for Difference Between Two Proportions

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

In random, independent samples of 225 adults and 250 teenagers who watched a certain television show, 99 adults and 125 teens indicated that they liked the show. Let $p_1$ be the proportion of all adults watching the show who liked it, and let $p_2$ be the proportion of all teens watching the show who liked it. Find a 90% confidence interval for $p_1-p_2.$

1. what is the lower limit of the 90% confidence interval
2. what is the upper limit of the 90% confidence interval

Comment: It would be nice to tell us what you tried.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I used the Estimating p1-p2 formula but I'm not getting the correct answer

Comment: There are several slightly different formulas in use, so don't necessarily expect CI bounds to agree _exactly_ with answer book.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Minitab output for the given data. You can find the formula in your text and
see if your results match results from Minitab. (Negative signs are because I put Adults first so estimated difference is $0.44 - 0.50 = -0.06.$)

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample    X    N  Sample p
1        99  225  0.440000
2       125  250  0.500000

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.06
90% CI for difference:  (-0.135289, 0.0152889)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = -1.31  P-Value = 0.190
```

Also, here are my results from R (which uses a continuity correction):

```
 prop.test(c(99,125), c(225,250), conf=.90)

    2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction

 data:  c(99, 125) out of c(225, 250) 
 X-squared = 1.4785, df = 1, p-value = 0.224
 alternative hypothesis: two.sided 
 90 percent confidence interval:
  -0.13951109  0.01951109 
 sample estimates:
 prop 1 prop 2 
   0.44   0.50
```

Comment: sorry I'm confused as too which one is your final answer

Comment: Bruce is right. I read the problem wrong so I deleted my comment since I used the wrong proportions.. Both of his answers are right but the continuity correction is used because we're estimating a discrete distribution with a normal (continuous) distribution.

Comment: @BruceET how do you go about using the continuity correction for the standard formula like I wrote below?? I thought it was .5/N, but what if the sample sizes aren't the same? I.E) n1 = 225 and n2 = 250.

Comment: @Brandon: Continuity correction is straightforward for one variable: Exmp: If $X \sim Binom(16,.5)$ and you want to get $P(X \le 7) = P(X < 8) =0.4018,$ you base norm aprx on $P(X < 7.5) \approx 0.4013$ --- in R using code  `pnorm(7.5, 8, 2) `. (Generally, expect about 2-place accuracy.) Comparing 2 binoms, the situation is more complex, and cont corr formulas vary depending on text/software (with some controversy). As you begin, best to use what's in your text/lect notes (whether w/o cont corr or whatever version with cont corr.) Notice that final answ amts to $(-.14, .02)$ either way.

Comment: @Brandon: For hyp test, I prefer Fisher Exact Test, which does not involve norm aprx. 'Inverting' it can give CI, but not implemented in R as far as I know. (But Fisher meth also controversial because it's 'conditional') // Sorry to see your Answ deleted rather than repaired; was hoping for chance to up-vote corrected version.

Comment: @BruceET I understand. Our methods in R were basically the same, but I didn't want to confuse OP with my incorrect answer. And fixing my version would have yielded in the same answer as yours, no need for 2 of the same answer... Thanks for the help and clarification! Cheers.

Comment: Olga: Please see my 1st Comment replying to @Brandon. Try to use formula in your text/notes. I gave both hoping one would match. Goal of most of us on this site is not to provide 'final answers' to hwk problems, but to guide you toward understanding subject matter. (Your down-votes are likely from users who were disappointed not to see what you tried before deciding you're stuck and asking for help.)

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was incorrect because I used the wrong proportions, but the method was correct. Since Bruce has the outputs from computer software (which everyone isn't familiar with) then I will supply the standard formula that can be done by hand:

```
 p1 = .44;
 p2 = .50;
 n1 = 225;
 n2 = 250;
```

$\left(\text{upper}=0.06\, + 1.64 \sqrt{\frac{\text{p1} (1-\text{p1})}{\text{n1}}+\frac{\text{p2} (1-\text{p2})}{\text{n2}}}\right)$

$\left(\text{lower}=0.06\, -1.64 \sqrt{\frac{\text{p1} (1-\text{p1})}{\text{n1}}+\frac{\text{p2} (1-\text{p2})}{\text{n2}}}\right)$

$\text{upper}=.0.06\, +1.64 \sqrt{\frac{0.44*0.56}{225}+\frac{0.5* 0.5}{250}}$

$\text{lower}=.0.06\, -1.64 \sqrt{\frac{0.44*0.56}{225}+\frac{0.5* 0.5}{250}}$

Thus, the interval is

```
  (-.015,.135)
```

Notice the *sign* difference because I used Teens - Adults. It is the same answer as above, but make sure to *interpret* it correctly. R is of course a lot easier and supplies much more information

Comment: Okay I was mixing up my formula numbers under the square root, this helped thanks